# Error while working on Automation Grant Access to database views / tables in snowflake schema

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a stored procedure to grant access to the Snowflake database table / views, the procedure compiled successfully but getting the below error while executing:

Step1:
What I am trying to do is select the records from the database table having the below column:

```
 "select PRIVILEGE, GRANTED_ON,NAME, GRANTED_TO,GRANTEE_NAME,TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, MODIFIED_ON from USERS_GRANTS_TO_ROLE_TBL" ;
```

Step2:
Get the values into the vairables, form a Grant syntax like below:

```
`GRANT ` + return_privilege + ` ON ` + return_granted_on + ` ` + return_table_catelog + `.` + return_table_schema + `.` + return_name + ` TO ` + return_granted_to + ` ` + return_grantee_name ;
```

Step3:
Insert the data into below table having columns as below:

```
"INSERT INTO TEST_GRANTS_TO_ROLE_SCRIPTS_TBL VALUES (" + return_table_catelog + "," + return_modified_on + "," + " " + sql_statement + ";" + " " + ")";
```

The below error encountered when I call the Stored Proc written using javascript language.

> SQL Error [1003] [42000]: Execution error in store procedure
> SAMPLE_TEST_USER_GRANTS: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at
> position 60 unexpected 'May'. syntax error line 1 at position 115
> unexpected 'GRANT'. At Statement.execute, line 46 position 20

Appreciate, if anyone can help me out with this.

```
var VAR_SQL_STMT = "select PRIVILEGE, GRANTED_ON,NAME, 
                           GRANTED_TO,GRANTEE_NAME,TABLE_CATALOG, 
                           TABLE_SCHEMA, MODIFIED_ON 
                    from USERS_GRANTS_TO_ROLE_TBL" ; 
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: VAR_SQL_STMT } );
/* Creates result set */ 
var res = stmt.execute(); 
while (res.next()) { 
   var return_privilege = res.getColumnValue(1); 
   var return_granted_on = res.getColumnValue(2); 
   var return_name = res.getColumnValue(3); 
   var return_granted_to = res.getColumnValue(4); 
   var return_grantee_name = res.getColumnValue(5); 
   var return_table_catelog = res.getColumnValue(6); 
   var return_table_schema = res.getColumnValue(7); 
   var return_modified_on = res.getColumnValue(8); 

   var sql_statement = GRANT  + return_privilege + ` ON ` + 
       return_granted_on + ` ` + return_table_catelog + . + 
       return_table_schema + . + return_name + ` TO ` + 
       return_granted_to + ` ` + return_grantee_name ; 
   var var_sql_text = "INSERT INTO TEST_GRANTS_TO_ROLE_SCRIPTS_TBL 
       VALUES (" + return_table_catelog + "," + return_modified_on + 
       "," + " " + sql_statement + ";" + " " + ")"; 
   var stmt1 = snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: var_sql_text } ); 
   stmt1.execute();
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you’d actually provided the SP code

Comment: please find the stored proc below:

Comment: I am unable to attach the stored proc

Comment: @NirmalKumarKosuru update your question with the code

Comment: The code exceeds character limit, when I tried to put the code in the comment.

Comment: So just post the sections of the code that are relevant to the error message i.e. a few lines before/after the lines mentioned in the error message

Comment: Already code is explained in steps let me put the code in some other form

Comment: var VAR_SQL_STMT = "select PRIVILEGE, GRANTED_ON,NAME, GRANTED_TO,GRANTEE_NAME,TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, MODIFIED_ON from USERS_GRANTS_TO_ROLE_TBL" ;
           var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
            {
             sqlText: VAR_SQL_STMT
            }
           );

Comment: /* Creates result set */
   var res = stmt.execute();
 
      while (res.next())  {
        
         var return_privilege = res.getColumnValue(1);
         var return_granted_on = res.getColumnValue(2);
   var return_name = res.getColumnValue(3);
            var return_granted_to = res.getColumnValue(4);
            var return_grantee_name = res.getColumnValue(5);
            var return_table_catelog = res.getColumnValue(6);
            var return_table_schema = res.getColumnValue(7);
            var return_modified_on = res.getColumnValue(8);

Comment: var sql_statement = `GRANT ` + return_privilege + ` ON ` + return_granted_on + ` ` + return_table_catelog + `.` + return_table_schema + `.` + return_name + ` TO ` + return_granted_to + ` ` + return_grantee_name ; 


            var var_sql_text = "INSERT INTO TEST_GRANTS_TO_ROLE_SCRIPTS_TBL VALUES (" + return_table_catelog + "," + return_modified_on + "," + " " + sql_statement + ";" + " " + ")"; 
             
             
             var stmt1 = snowflake.createStatement(
            {
             sqlText: var_sql_text
            }
           );
   stmt1.execute();

Answer (score 0):

In your definition of var sql_statement you are missing quotes round a number of strings e.g. GRANT and the periods. It should look something like this:

```
var sql_statement = 'GRANT ' + return_privilege + ' ON ' + 
       return_granted_on + ' ' + return_table_catelog + '.' + 
       return_table_schema + '.' + return_name + ' TO ' + 
       return_granted_to + ' ' + return_grantee_name ;
```

Comment: I tried this as well but no luck

Comment: Please find the quotes are not missing for below:
var sql_statement = `GRANT ` + return_privilege + ` ON ` + return_granted_on + ` ` + return_table_catelog + `.` + return_table_schema + `.` + return_name + ` TO ` + return_granted_to + ` ` + return_grantee_name ;

Comment: but still getting error:

Comment: SQL Error [1003] [42000]: Execution error in store procedure SAMPLE_TEST2:
SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 60 unexpected 'May'.
syntax error line 1 at position 115 unexpected 'GRANT'.
At Statement.execute, line 38 position 20

Comment: I don’t know what this means “Please find the quotes are not missing for below” when the code you posted below this statement is missing the quotes

Comment: Finally I made it work. Thanks for all of you, try to help and figure out the issue. but I could figure out by myself.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues,The issue was Insert is failing for Date field coming in
a incorrect format. Added the below to the insert dynamic script as below:

```
return_modified_on date column toISOString()
"INSERT INTO TEST_GRANTS_TO_ROLE_SCRIPTS_TBL VALUES" 
+ "(" + " " + "'" + return_table_catelog + "'"+ "," + "'"
+ return_modified_on.toISOString() + "'"+ "," + "'" 
+ sql_statement + "'"+ ")" +";";
```